# Compare-Object API response with text file shows everything is different

Tags: powershell, compare

I have a Web API that returns an HTML string which I want to compare with a html file on my local machine.

To do so, I have the following code

```
$Result = (Invoke-WebRequest `
                -Uri "{uri}" `
                -Headers @{"some-header", "some-value"}).Content

$TestContent = Get-Content -Path ($RepositoryLocation + "index.html") -Raw
$Equal = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $TestContent -DifferenceObject $Result
```

When I now use `Write-Hosts $Equal` it displays me that the whole content is different

When I use `Write-Host $Equal.SideIndicator` it displays me `=> <=` which also indicates that the complete file is different

Furthermore, using the command with `-IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent` displays empty result, so like I said, no lines are the same.

---

So what I tried next was to save the Content of `$Result` into a text file and compare them then, but still, it told me, that the whole file is different.

---

I then used diffchecker.com as well as JetBrains IDEs integrated comparison tool, to check for differences. Both tools told me that the content is identical. I'm losing my mind, why does PowerShell tell me they have complete different content?

Sadly, I cannot post the content of the API response as well as the content of the index.html

---

What I thought maybe could be the reason is

- Encoding, however both are UTF8
- Line endings, however no diff if I use CL, CL RF or RF on the file
- Some hidden characters (tabs instead of spaces) but I activated to see that on JetBrains IDE and they still are identical.

How do I know what's causing this issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `Compare-Object` is the right choice here. As the name says, it's for objects. Why not use the equals-operator `-eq` or `string.Equals`?

```
$equal = $testContent -eq $result
# or
$equal = $testContent.Equals($result)
```

`Compare-Object` does not do line-by-line-comparison if both are just single strings. So your strings are not equal, as long as there's any tiny difference, as much as just an extra line-feed at the end, etc.

You could try several things:

```
# trim
$equal = $testContent.Trim() -eq $result.Trim()

# case-insensitive comparison
$equal = $testContent.Equals($result, 'OrdinalIgnoreCase')

# or both
$equal = $testContent.Trim().Equals($result.Trim(), 'OrdinalIgnoreCase')
```

Btw: If you **do** want a line-by-line-comparison, you have to split up the strings into lines first, e.g.:

```
Compare-Object ($testContent -split "`r`n") ($result -split "`r`n")
```

Comment: If you check [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7#example-1---compare-the-content-of-two-text-files) you'll see that they even have an example for text files and it says that it even checks line by line what differences there are, so if I understand correctly, this should work, shouldn't it?   
I can't simply use `-eq` since I need the diffs. What I did now was using `git diff` (it's for local development only) and this works, I was just wondering, because IMO this should work with `Compare-Object`

Comment: @Musterknabe That's because `Get-Content` (what is used in the example) returns all lines as an array of strings, but `Get-Contant -Raw` will return the entire content as a single string, and then it won't work as you want it to.